# не подгружает txt файл

Tags: jquery, ajax

Когда пытаюсь загрузить текстовик в массив

```js
    var linesArray = [];
  $.get('isnotvalue.txt', function(data) {
    linesArray = data.split(/\n/);
}, 'text');
```

браузер выдает ошибку:

> Failed to load file:// ..(путь).. isnotvalue.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Суть в том, что вы пытаетесь получить данные локально, тогда как можно получить по протоколу, например http или https, для этого разместите файл на сервере (можно локальном) и оттуда его уже пытайтесь получить запросом.

Comment: Кроссдоменные запросы в локальных файлах блокируются только Хромом, попробуйте в Фаерфокс